# Multiple Off Campus Menu

Tags: javascript, dry

I am using multiple off campus menus on my site. So as a user clicks on a certian link to a store they can get a off campus menu with information pertaining to that particular store. I am trying to minimize the JS code so that I don't have a open and close function for each span link that opens and closes a menu. I have tried to create one function that will different menus as to follow a DRY coding practice. I initially tried a switch statement but this only partially worked and I am left at a dead end. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you and have a blessed day.

```js
// // prj 1
function workOpenNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjOne').style.width = '100%';
}

function workCloseNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjOne').style.width = '0%';
}

// // prj 2
function workTwoOpenNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjTwo').style.width = '100%';
}

function workTwoCloseNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjTwo').style.width = '0%';
}

// // prj 3
function workThreeOpenNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjThree').style.width = '100%';
}

function workThreeCloseNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjThree').style.width = '0%';
}
```

```html
<span class="wrk-link span-title" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="workOpenNav()">
    Store #1
</span>

 <div id="prjOne" class="wrk-overlay overLay">
 // Content
 </div>

 <span class="wrk-link span-title" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="workTwoOpenNav()">
  Store #2
  </span>
  
   <div id="prjTwo" class="wrk-overlay overLay">
 // Content
 </div>
  
 <span class="wrk-link span-title" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="workThreeOpenNav()">
 Store #3
</span>

 <div id="prjThree" class="wrk-overlay overLay">
 // Content
 </div>
```

Comment: You can pass the element in the `onclick` with `onclick="openNav(this.id)"`. Then in the javascript code, can have the id as a parameter
`function openNav(elemId) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this together.  Take these first two functions:

```
function workOpenNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjOne').style.width = '100%';
}

function workCloseNav() {
  document.getElementById('prjOne').style.width = '0%';
}
```

Let's find what they have in common, and turn what they do *not* have in common into input variables.  In this case, the percentage is the only thing different.  So:

```
function workNav(pct) {
  document.getElementById('prjOne').style.width = pct;
}
```

This one function now does the work of two.  The other functions you have can similarly be combined into a single function with one input.  Let's do that now:

```
function workTwoNav(pct) {
  document.getElementById('prjTwo').style.width = pct;
}

function workThreeNav(pct) {
  document.getElementById('prjThree').style.width = pct;
}
```

But we're not done!  Notice that these three functions I've made have mostly everything in common, only the control ID is different.  Let's turn that into another parameter!

```
function workNav(id, pct) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = pct;
}
```

Now, all of your functions have been reduced to a single function, which can be called like so:

```
workNav("prjOne", "100%");
```

Now, we're still not quite done.  Let's clean this up and make it more clear.  Your function is intended to show or hide the indicated element, right?  So let's rename it to make that intent more clear, and let's tweak the second parameter a bit:

```
function showNav(id, show) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = show ? "100%" : "0%";
}
```

Now, it can be used accordingly.  To show:

```
showNav("prjOne", true)
```

And to hide:

```
showNav("prjOne", false)
```

Why turn the second parameter into a `true/false`?  It will be easier for the programmer to get right.  `"100%"` it would be pretty easy to drop a `0`, or the percentage sign. Those typos won't generate an error in your browsers console, but if you make a typo like `tru`, you'll get an error, which you can then fix.  Things are easier to fix when the error is made apparent. Ultimately this change comes down to programmer preference, and isn't necessary to achieve your goals.  Would you ever set the width to `50%`, or is it always all-or-nothing?  Clearer intent is achieved using the boolean.

Comment: Wow Thank you. that makes total sense. So the function reads the current state of the off campus window and depending on the state of open (true) or closed (false) the turnery operator will determine the functions out put. Did I get that about right? Still learning JS and i truly appreciate the help.

Comment: However, I am getting an error that it can not read the property style?                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                              menu.js:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at showNav (menu.js:147)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):609)                                                              Thanks again!!

Comment: @ShargeneZangana The element wasn't found in that case.